# How do i use router? login component to tabs component nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using this
https://github.com/NativeScript/template-tab-navigation-ng
template as a boilerplate.What i am trying to do is add a new root login component to this and navigate to tabs component after pressing button from login component.
[image: file structure]

login-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { LoginComponent } from "./login.component";


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "/login", component: LoginComponent },



];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { TabsComponent } from "./tabs.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "/tabs", component: TabsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class TabsRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    { path: "", redirectTo: "/tabs", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "tabs", loadChildren: "./tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { TabsComponent } from "./tabs/tabs.component";


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
LoginComponent        
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,

    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TabsComponent} from '../tabs/tabs.component'
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { 



  }

  ngOnInit() { 



  }
  loginbutton(){

    alert("lgoniasdasd");
    this.router.navigate(["tabs"]);



  }

}
```

there is a button in login page with loginbutton function

Comment: Hello ! I cannot understand your question. What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: after adding one component to project(login component which is just an empty component with a button) how do i navigate to another component(tabs component)

Comment: This should work : `this.router.navigate(["tabs"]);` . If it is giving any error please share error.

Comment: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation